# Defining a C Macro from the Android Code

Tags: android, c, macros, java-native-interface

I have a header file header.h in which variable is defined to be x.

**#define variable X**

on the basis of variable x I  have a structure y in a c file -  program.c :

```
#include header.h

Structure y 
{
int val[variable];
.
.
//other elements

}


void func()
{
//here instance of y->val[variable] is used heavily

}
```

this c code(header.h and program.c)  is a JNI code and I am making a shared lib .so out of it and loading it in the Android java code .
Now lately i came to know a bug in my code and the solution is to dynamically define the variable value to x.
Now besides passing this value from the ANdroid to JNI is there a way I can directly #define a macro in Android java say MACRODEFINED_FROM_ANDROID language for C 
so that in header file becomes like this :

```
#ifdef MACRODEFINED_FROM_ANDROID
#define variable x
#elif
#define variable y
#endif
```

Other solution is I will create two shared library one with variable = x and other with variable = y and load it dynamically in the android code.

PLz suggest.

Rgds,
Saurabh

Answer (score 0):

According to this, there are some macros to help you test if you are compiling for android

http://annoyingtechnicaldetails.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/which-macros-does-the-android-ndk-gcc-define/

On my system:

```
# $CC  -dM -E - < /dev/null | grep -i android
#define __ANDROID__ 1
# echo $CC
android-ndk-r7b//toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin//arm-linux-   androideabi-gcc --sysroot=platforms/android-9/arch-arm
```